# Make Items Float to Each Side in a Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, navigation

```
<body>
    <div id="nav">
        <div id="nav-wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">ERIN</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="nav-wrapper1">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">item #2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item #3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item #4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item #5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The code you see above is what makes up my navigation bar.

Below is the CSS:

```
body
{ 
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0; 
    font-family: Arial; 
    font-size: 16px; 
    background-color: #F1F1F1; 
    height: 2000px; 
}

#nav
{ 
    background-color: #222; 
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%; 
    top: 0; 
}
    #nav-wrapper
    { 
        width: 960px; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        text-align: left; 
    }

    #nav-wrapper1
    { 
        width: 960px; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        text-align: right;
    }


        #nav ul
        { 
            list-style-type: none; 
            padding: 0; 
            margin: 0; 
        }
            #nav ul li
            { display: inline-block; }

                #nav ul li:hover
                { background-color: #333; }

                    #nav ul li a,visited
                    { 
                        color: #CCC; 
                        display: block; 
                        padding: 15px; 
                        text-decoration: none; 
                    }
```

My problem is I am trying to get the link with my name in it to float to the left side, while the items numbers float to the right side. but they are just not combining into one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First, lets understand the problem.**

You currently have the following two `CSS` classes:

```
#nav-wrapper
    { 
        width: 960px; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        text-align: left; 
    }

    #nav-wrapper1
    { 
        width: 960px; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        text-align: right;
    }
```

This two classes are applied on `div` elements. `div` elements are by default `block-level` elements. This means, they occupy the full space in terms of a line on the `html` page. So, the first change you will have to make is to remove the "blockness". So, you can define them as `inline-block`.

Secondly, you have defined them with 960px width. This will make them to occupy the said amount of space irrespective of whether this is needed or not. By defining `display:inline-block`, they will occupy only the amount of space that is needed. Hence, you don't need to explicitly set the width property on them.

**Now, the solution**

Just modify your two CSS classes as follows :

```
#nav-wrapper {
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
#nav-wrapper1 {
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

This will give you what you are looking for.

```css
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    height: 2000px;
}
#nav {
    background-color: #222;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#nav-wrapper {
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
#nav-wrapper1 {
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}
#nav ul li a, visited {
    color: #CCC;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="nav">
        <div id="nav-wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">ERIN</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="nav-wrapper1">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">item #2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">item #3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">item #4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">item #5</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @ER1N I have edited my answer to explain the underlying concept as well. Read it and the next time you will be able to solve this by yourself!!

Comment: Thanks again, I re-read what you wrote in your answer and it makes perfect sense